# Closing websockets by apollo client react nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, apollo-client, hotchocolate

I'm using Apollo Client with React, Next.js, and TypeScript to subscribe to a GraphQL server created with HotChocolate. While my subscriptions work correctly, I'm having trouble closing the WebSocket connections created by them. Even after navigating away from the component that contains the subscription, the WebSocket connections remain open, which is causing performance issues on the client and the server. How can I properly close the WebSocket connections created by Apollo Client subscriptions in my React/Next.js app?